Man capturing creature right before death
Need help identifying an old black & white B horror movie.
A man finds a way to live forever by capturing a creature right before almost killing himself. The creature feeds on fear and appears right before someone dies. He tries to do the same for his daughter, but an accident happens and she ends up be-headed, but still alive. The man has an argument with her husband about whether or not to release the creature and let her die.
The language spoken is English. Not sure when it was made, but guessing somewhere in the 1950's.

Hi there. Welcome to the site. In order to identify the movie you may need to add additional information in your question. Please realize that identify-this-movie questions are very personal, and may not help the group as much as other discussions. Because of these limitations, please follow these guidelines for such identification questions: http://movies.stackexchange.com/tags/identify-this-movie/info The community here will be happy to help you. Once again, welcome!

Thanks for the extra details. This sounds pretty much like the plot of The Asphyx, but it's from 1972, in color and the daughter dies after she's beheaded (by a guillotine).

I am the Kathleen that asked this question before I set up an account. And since I am new here I cannot make a comment yet, not even on my pre-account question. 
Yes Walt, The Asphyx is the answer.

English country squire Sir Hugo Cunningham searches for immortality by literally 'bottling up' the Spirit of the Dead, or Asphyx.




I saw the movie years ago & in my mind I must have turned it black & white when it wasn't. Thanks for solving the mystery!
